# c# key attibute - How can I insert my own value as a key

Tags: c#, key

I'm using Entity Framework v4, Code First. I'm decorating the property that corresponds to the primary key with KeyAttribute, as so: [Key].I want to be able to set this property explicitly instead of having it autoincrement. thanks

Comment: You will have to provide a little more detail for us to be able to help you I'm afraid. Code snippets always help as well

Comment: Let me translate: He's using Entity Framework v4, Code First. He's decorating the property that corresponds to his primary key with KeyAttribute, as so: [Key]. He wants to be able to set this property explicitly instead of having it autoincrement.

Comment: thanks Sapph. this is much clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the type to a string, that should take care of the auto-increment issue.

Edit:
Just in response to your wanting to use an SSN as the primary key, I would advise against storing an SSN as plain-text in your database. Unless you have an overwhelming need to do it and have some pretty tight security in place I would recommend encrypting it before placing it in the database. There are lots of legal ramifications to exposing SSNs, and plain text SSNs in a database is asking for identity theft attempts ;)

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing if there's a way to use an `int` PK and turning off autoincrement.

Comment: @Sapph I don't know if there is, but the original post mentioned storing SSNs or something similar, seemed like a good time to use a string which would get around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int fookey {get;set;}
```

Take a look at the [DatabaseGeneratedOption Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).